# Java threads problem

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a problem with java threads:

```
public class MyClass{

 public void Core(){
  runTools(); //here I would like to call runTools() method
 }

 public void runTools(){

  final String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C sources.exe";

  Runnable doRun = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     Process tool_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run_tool);
     } 
    catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }; 
  Thread th = new Thread(doRun);
  th.start();

 }
}
```

If I do this, then I don't know why, but the thread doesn't work. Please give me some ideas to create a thread. I have already been seen lots of examples, but I should some code such as my example here. Thanks!

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: beware that your whole code must have a leading tab (or 4+ leading spaces) to be formatted correctly

Comment: This mostly looks ok, assuming you are calling `Core()` at some point.  Remember that the output of your process will not go to standard output automatically - are you absolutely sure it is not being invoked?

Comment: How do you know the thread isn't working?  You could check by changing your run_tool variable to something like `cmd /c echo time /t > c:\temp\thread_output.txt` and check that the file is created in temp

Comment: why using `cmd.exe` and not calling `sources.exe` directly? It's no error, but I think it's not needed. I would, at least for testing, add a `System.out.println("starting...");` at the start of the run method. Maybe another one after an additional `tool_proc.waitFor()`...

Answer (score 1):

At first, if you just want to execute an external command <s>and do not bother about its output</s>*, then using a dedicated thread is unnecessary, since the process itself will already run in parallel to your application, so the `exec()` call will not really hang your programm.

Nevertheless your code looks correct to me. You should check the working directory of your application (maybe `cmd.exe` cannot find your `sources.exe`) and evaluate the output the process you start gives you, by directing the streams of `tool_proc.getErrorStream()` and `tool_proc.getInputStream()` to `System.out` or logging them.

**EDIT:**
* The [Java documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) states you always should read the `InputStream`s of your processes as failing to do so might result in filling up a system buffer, which will eventually hang the process.

Answer (score 0):

problem 1 You create object for Runnable Interface,that is never possible.

Runnable *obj=new Runnable();   // this is not correct

problem 2 You write definition for Run() method  with in the another method runTools()

we can create object for a class that implements The Runnable interface.

Due to these your code is not working.

Try the fallowing way

```
public class MyClassName1 implements Runnable
{
  public void start()
  {
    //here you can call your method:runTools()

      runTool();

  }
}
public void runTools()
{

final String run_tool ="cmd.exe /C sources.exe";
    try 
    {
     Process tool_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(run_tool);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is my main class of the programe

```
public class MyClassName2 
{
  public static void main(String[] ars)
  {
    Runnable *obj1=new MyClassName1();
     Thread t=new Thread(obj);
     t.start()
  }
```

I hope this helps to you